# EF won't create empty database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I'm trying to create a database through EF, to store members and their locations.
I've had a look at other examples, but no matter what I do, when I run my program, my database doesn't get created.

I've noticed that the example I followed created a DataInitializer class, which puts some records in the database. I haven't done this yet, since I would like to check if my database gets created with the right columns.
Could not having data in the database be the problem?

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Lid> Leden { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Locatie> Locaties { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new LidConfiguration());
        builder.ApplyConfiguration(new LocatieConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Appsettings.json:

```
{ "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\sqlexpress;Database=Taijitan;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"},
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

In the example I followed, startup.cs also contains

```
services.AddScoped<BeerhallDataInitializer>();
```

and all the way at the bottom

```
beerhallDataInitializer.InitializeData();
```

I don't suppose this is what's causing the problem, but I'm not so sure anymore

EDIT:

```
public class BeerhallDataInitializer
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

    public BeerhallDataInitializer(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void InitializeData()
    {
        _dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
        if (_dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated())
        { *create new objects and add them to _dbcontext*
          _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you configure EF to use that connection string? And what `BeerhallDataInitializer` looks like?

Comment: If you want an empty database, then you don't need a database initializer, you can use one of the existing ones. Did you try to create a DbContext with only the string parameter "MyDatabase"? Did you try as initializer `DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationDbContext>`, did it hit your breakpoint in `OnModelCreating`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to run a migration you first need to create the migration with the command:
'dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate'
Secondly, then you need to run your migration with the command:
'dotnet ef database update' or by creating some code that run missing migrations which i can assume it's what beerhallDataInitializer.InitializeData() does but can't know for sure since I have no more information about it but to be able to migrate via code you need the reference to the IApplicationBuilder like so in the startup.cs file:

```
            DbInitializer.Migrate<ApplicationDbContext>(app);
```

and my dbinitilizer is :

```
public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Migrate<T>(IApplicationBuilder app) where T : DbContext
        {
            using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
            {
                scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>().Database.Migrate();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps anything just comment bellow but give more information about what you have done

Edit:

try changing your connection string to:

```
Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Taijitan;Integrated Security=True
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I don't remember seeing Migrate in the example I used, I edited the post and added data initializer, which contains enureDeleted() and ensureCreated(), is this something similar to migrate?

Comment: Yes your ensureCreated works aswell,  do you have a Migrations folder? If yes check my edit on the post and tell me if it helped, if not then you have to create a migration